# Http request from google cloud instance to random website ingress or egress?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-networking

I have a program running in my google cloud instance.It pings 10,000 website every 5 min to check their website availability. Each request is a http **head** request, So the response size will be 1kb per request.

My question is does google charge me for this request? 
Each request from my instance is ingress or egress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be charged by the total amount of data going out of the GCP zone - https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing (ingress is no charge).

Your outgoing HTTP requests will count as egress traffic, the response is ingress and free.